# Building Docker Images without Dependencies?

Tags: docker

I am rather new to Docker so I don't know if that would be against the principles of how Docker is supposed to work but is it possible to mark dependencies in a Dockerfile as "lazy-loaded" of some sorts so they don't get included in an image built from it?

The concrete case here is that when developping a very small app of maybe even less than 1MB in size - e.g. a "microservice" REST-API in .Net Core - an image built from my Dockerfile has a size of 207MB and more as this is exactly the size of the .NET runtime my service depends on.

Is it possible to configure an image so it only contains my code instead of also kind of delivering the rather large runtime with my image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would your code run if it did not have a runtime to sit on top of?

Comment: I was thinking that when installing the image, maybe Docker could install other images my image depends on (the runtime, for example) automatically, without having my image to contain the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you have to install everything you going to need in your app. The same way as you would instal whole .net core on your OS to run any even simplest .net app.

Another point is that out of those 207MB about 100Mb belongs to win nano server. at least it was this way last time i've looked at it.

On the bright side. Minimal linux image is just few MB. And .Net Core supposed to be cross platform one.

**So i would recommend look into this way if you want to make image smaller. Here is some link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux**

p.s. never tried .net core on linux myself - though it alway was interested. because it supposed to be faster as for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it is not really in the spirit of docker. It is better to front load your installation when you build your image, so that you can avoid doing it at runtime, every time your app starts up. It could take a few minutes.

If your use case really needs it, I would check out the alpine linux docker image as a base image. It is quite small. Then when your container starts, run a bash script that

1. installs dotnet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-alpine
2. runs your app

I am paraphrasing here, but in spirit this will work

```
# This is the large dotnet image, but it is ony used to build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

COPY Code/. ./Code/
# you will need to add some flags here to get it to compile to alpine
RUN dotnet publish ./Code -c Release

# This is your runtime image that is actually loaded into a container
FROM alpine AS runtime
# Copy compiled files from build to runtime image
COPY --from=build [Your alpine publish directory from above] .

# Add a bash script from your dev environment that will do the work
COPY installDotnetAndStartupScript.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["installDotnetAndStartupScript.sh"]
```

Comment: The tip with installing necessary dependencies afterwards seems interesting, I've seen different approaches with using apt-get in the process. Nonetheless, doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose as when you integrate it into your build Dockerfile, it will still end up in the final image?

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to minimize an image you want to transmit, optimally without any third party software. So my approach would be to build an image using just my binaries and exporting it via save. Maybe it could be combined with another docker file that loads both the runtime and my image to run a container from?  
The "runtime" Dockerfile could use my reduced image, copy the binaries, load the .net runtime and call dotnet <name>.dll to run my binaries? Does that make sense?

Comment: On installing necessary dependencies: anything that you do in a "RUN" command in your docker file will go into the image, but it you use an "ENTRYPOINT" or "CMD" command, that will not be executed until your docker container starts.

Comment: On combining it with another image: yes that is totally possible, and it sounds like it is a cleaner solution to what you are going for, especially if bash isn't your thing. Just leave a lot of time for debuging the docker inception and set --privilidged=true when you run the outermost container: https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/